# Reboot and shutdown from MATE

Tags: lightdm, mate

When I start MATE 1.6.0 from LightDM in Ubuntu 13.10, I can't reboot or shut down the system or shut it down because the buttons to do that don't appear.
The only thing I can do is terminate the session of the current user and then use the buttons on lightdm. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: what happens if u type `sudo reboot` in the terminal?

Comment: @Alvar the systems reboots as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `mate-power-manager` package. Otherwise none of the power functions will work correctly.